# Is there any way to check timer is runned at defined period?

Tags: android

i developed an application which sends birthday wishes on facebook wall, but when i am calling someone at same time that i set for sending wishes, then wishes failed to post on facebook wall.
I used Alarm Manager first.
But i want to use timer class and in that timer class i want to check that message is posted to wall or not at defined time or if not then i want to reschedule the timer class to send post. 
i have this code for timer class

```
 private final Timer clockTimer;

    private class Task extends TimerTask {
        public void run() {
            timerHandler.sendEmptyMessage(0);
        }
    }

    private final Handler timerHandler = new Handler() {
        public void handleMessage (Message  msg) {
            // runs in context of the main thread
            timerSignal();
        }
    };

    private List<SystemTimerListener> clockListener = new ArrayList<SystemTimerListener>();

    public SystemTimerAndroid() {
        clockTimer = new Timer();
        clockTimer.schedule(new Task(), 1000, 1000);
    }

    private void timerSignal() {
        for(SystemTimerListener listener : clockListener)
            listener.onSystemTimeSignal();      
    }

    public void killTimer() {
        clockTimer.cancel();
    }

    @Override
    public void addListener(SystemTimerListener listener) {
        clockListener.add(listener);        
    }
```

this code is repeating after every second so i want to check if it runned for first time then stop the timer and reschedule for next day and so on...
Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

you can check it by putting System.out.println() or any Logcat. you can also check is by putting Toast in Timer Run Method. So Everytime when Run Method executes , the Toast will be appear on the screen for notification.

Comment: :but if not then how to check and reschedule after some period automatic without any interference .

Comment: Please look at to this example link http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/Java/0120__Development/SchedulingaTimerTasktoRunRepeatedly.htm